# Zend framewok change dns for application error

Tags: php, zend-framework, configuration, installation, dns

I want to add virtual host for the application quickstart but this error occur,
I go to

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc  path
```

and add this to hosts file, I run the file as administrator to allow changes but this error occur which is

```
   "Check whether this file is open with another application"
```

My windows is 7 /64bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change file permissions clickfile > properties > system tab > and change permissions as you need